# In rock climbing what does the term "Flash" mean?

Tags: rock-climbing, climbing, terminology

If someone "flashes" a climb what does this mean?

Comment: Can we extend this into a general climbing lingo question (like these "canonical questions" some other SE sites have)? Already in the answer "onsight" is mentioned, but e.g. "send" is not, which is necessary (the explanation "without stopping, resting" at the time of writing is ambiguous, as you can rest and stop as much as you want, if you don't weight the belaying chain). Then we could also include "red-point" and maybe "pink-point" (or not as it's outdated). What do you think?

Comment: Sure @imsodin. It's a wiki answer so feel free to edit

Comment: Yeah that covers it. Keeping this question as a signpost